# method collect(Collector<? super Dish,A,R>) in the type Stream<Dish> not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#3-of ?,String>)

Tags: java-8

I am getting the below error for Java 8 code developed below. In this example, trying to join all the names of the Dish Name into a single variable. With the below code I got this `"The method collect(Collector<? super Dish,A,R>) in the type Stream<Dish> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#3-of ?,String>)"`.

**Dish.java**

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Dish {
    public enum Type { MEAT, FISH, OTHER }

    private final String name;
    private final boolean vegetarian;
    private final int calories;
    private final Type type;

    public static final List<Dish> menu =
            Arrays.asList( new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH),
                           new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH));
}
```

**Here is the main method**

```
String shortMenu = Dish.menu.stream().map(Dish::getName).collect(joining());
System.out.println(shortMenu);

String shortMenu1 = Dish.menu.stream().collect(joining()); //line-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the Lombok annotation `@Data` which automatically creates a `toString()` method, so presumably you were expecting line-3 to work. The `toString()` method is only called automatically when you add it to a string (i.e. a literal string or another variable declared as String). For other uses, you need to call `toString()` explicitly. Therefore, line-3 should be:

```
String shortMenu1 = Dish.menu.stream().map(Dish::toString).collect(joining()); //line-3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only join `CharSequence`s as the `Collectors::joining` mandates, your Stream on the other hand is `Stream<Dish>` (in that line-3), it will simply not match the definition and not compile - which is what you get.

Comment: How can we fixed this? What exact change do I need?

Comment: @Sayali but you already did have everything ok via `Dish.menu.stream().map(Dish::getName).collect(joining());` if this is not what you need, might care to explain may be a bit more?